# mypy: How to define return value as a list of sub-class instances

Tags: python, mypy, static-typing

I'am trying to define a return value of method `foo` as a list of `AbstractChild` sub-class instances, but mypy keeps giving me an error.

```py
class AbstractParent(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self) -> List["AbstractChild"]: pass


class AbstractChild(ABC):
    pass


class Parent(AbstractParent):
    def foo(self) -> List["Child"]: pass
#   ^ mypy: error Return type "List[Child]" of "foo" incompatible with return type "List[AbstractChild]" in supertype "AbstractParent"


class Child(AbstractChild):
    pass
```

Changing the return type from the list to a single value will make mypy to stop complaining which I find quite strange, but I'm still getting used to python type system so I might be missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mypy` is correct here because your `Parent` doesn't implement `AbstractParent` correctly - to do that, it should define a method `foo` that returns a list of `AbstractChild`ren, not `Child`ren. This is because collections are not polymorphic (and this is true for other languages too, e.g. Java): `List[AbstractChild]` is not the same type as `List[Child]`, and `List[Child]` doesn't inherit from `List[AbstractChild]` just because `Child` does. If we wouldn't have this restriction, errors like this would be possible:

```
class AbstractChild(ABC):
    pass

class Child(AbstractChild):
    pass

class GrandChild(AbstractChild):
    pass

grandchildren: List[GrandChild] = [GrandChild()]
all_children: List[AbstractChild] = grandchildren
all_children.append(Child())
grandchild: GrandChild = grandchildren[0]  # would pass typechecks but is a Child, actually
```

(this is a rephrased example of [Jon Skeet's answer for a similar question in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/2650249)).

Java, for example, catches this type of errors at compilation and requires explicit covariance, e.g. `List<? extends Child>` for reading from and `List<? super Child>` for writing to the list.

In your case, you would introduce a generic type as well. In the example below, I change `AbstractParent` to return a `List` of elements having the same type `C` that can be anything that subclasses `AbstractChild`, and `Parent` is a concrete implementation of the generic `AbstractChild` with concrete child type `Child`:

```
from typing import List, TypeVar, Generic


C = TypeVar('C', bound='AbstractChild')


class AbstractParent(ABC, Generic[C]):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self) -> List[C]: pass


class Parent(AbstractParent["Child"]):
    def foo(self) -> List["Child"]:
        return []
```

For more examples, check out the [Generics](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html) chapter from `mypy` docs, in particular the [Variance of generic types](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#variance-of-generic-types) section.